# Ubuntu 14.04: Can I automatically deactivate my touchpad when a USB-mouse is connected?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

i tried the touchpad indicator app. To set to disable/enable the touchpad when a mouse is plugged in or out. But this dose not work for Ubuntu 14.04 versions.

https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting for **Ubuntu 15.10** and I believe it is applicable for 14.04 too. The feature can be accessed by using *Dconf editor*. Navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` and change the `send-events` path.

This can be done via command line as well. The following command gives the output:

```
$ gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events
enum
'enabled'
'disabled'
'disabled-on-external-mouse'
```

Of course last property is of our pursue. To change the settings type this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events disabled-on-external-mouse
```

Again, you may want to revert things. If so, run following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled
```

### **Update:**

I can only confirm it works with a wired USB mouse.

Comment: According to me this is the best option to disable the touchpad on mouse connectivity, as this doesn't require installing anything else. This option should be in the main settings UI of ubuntu itself.

Comment: this doesn't work with bluetooth mouse